# javascript json find value for each given path; handle errors

Tags: javascript, json

Below is a JSON object that I receive in response. A few remarks:

- This is just part of the object
- The object does not have the same keys for all companies

JSON:

```
{
    "company": {
        "result": [
            {
                "profile": {
                    "address": "One Microsoft Way",
                    "bosses": [
                        {
                            "name": "Mr. Satya  Nadella",
                            "age": 53,
                            "totalPay": {
                                "raw": 13603180,
                                "fmt": "13.6M",
                                "longFmt": "13,603,180"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Mr. Bradford L. Smith",
                            "age": 61,
                            "title": "Pres & Chief Legal Officer",
                            "totalPay": {
                                "raw": 4265576,
                                "fmt": "4.27M",
                                "longFmt": "4,265,576"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "auditRisk": 1,
                },
                "statistics": {
                    "enterpriseValue": {
                        "raw": 1570244395008,
                        "fmt": "1.57T",
                    },
                    "profitMargins": {
                        "raw": 0.32285
                    },
                    "financialCurrency": "USD"
                }
            }
        ],
        "error": null
    }
}
```

I would like to:

- check a number of paths in this object
- if the path points to a string value, return the value if existent
- if the path points to an array, loop through the array to return the path for each array element
- if a specific element is named in the path, only return that one
- there needs to be proper error handling

Script

```
var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

var paths = arr[
    "profile/address",                 <-- return the value
    "profile/sector",                  <-- does not exist, return false
    "profile/bosses/name",             <-- is an array with 2 elements, return both names
    "profile/bosses/1/age"             <-- only return age of second element
    "statistics/enterpriseValue/fmt",  <-- return the value
    "profitMargins/fmt",               <-- does not exist, return false
]
```

Expected output:

```
One Microsoft Way
false
Mr. Satya Nadella
Mr. Bradford L. Smith
53
false
```

I tried for quite some time now, but am getting confused. Can you help me out?

```
for (path in paths) {
    var steps = path.split('/')
    
    for (step in steps) {
        if (step.hasOwnProperty(steps[step+1])) {
            if (typeof path[step] === "object") {
                // array, so loop again?
            }
            if (typeof path[step] === undefined) {
                // value doesn't exist?
                
                return false;
            }
            if (typeof path[step] !== undefined) {
                return path[step].value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you start at the root of your object? What happens if more than 1 match is found for your partial path? If you start at `company.result` path, it should be easy enough to see if there is a `profile` property and then an `address` property for `'profile/address'`. Same basically goes for arrays afterwards

Comment: Looking at your paths, how flexible / open are you for changes to it? For example, to differentiate between an array index and a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are some things to be considered first, so I only start searching the object at the following path

```
getPath( data, 'company/result/0' )
```

Which makes it a lot easier for me to start searching for your specified paths instead.

I think the syntax you choose for the properties might not be the easiest one, as it's a bit harder to decide whether to search in all elements or just a single item in the array (say, you would be looking for something like `length` of an item).

Sub arrays still exist in this result, but you could flatten the results if you wanted it to.

```js
const data = {
    "company": {
        "result": [
            {
                "profile": {
                    "address": "One Microsoft Way",
                    "bosses": [
                        {
                            "name": "Mr. Satya  Nadella",
                            "age": 53,
                            "totalPay": {
                                "raw": 13603180,
                                "fmt": "13.6M",
                                "longFmt": "13,603,180"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Mr. Bradford L. Smith",
                            "age": 61,
                            "title": "Pres & Chief Legal Officer",
                            "totalPay": {
                                "raw": 4265576,
                                "fmt": "4.27M",
                                "longFmt": "4,265,576"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "auditRisk": 1,
                },
                "statistics": {
                    "enterpriseValue": {
                        "raw": 1570244395008,
                        "fmt": "1.57T",
                    },
                    "profitMargins": {
                        "raw": 0.32285
                    },
                    "financialCurrency": "USD"
                }
            }
        ],
        "error": null
    }
};

const pathsToFind = [
  "profile/address",
  "profile/sector",                 
  "profile/bosses/name",            
  "profile/bosses/1/age",            
  "statistics/enterpriseValue/fmt",
  "profitMargins/fmt"
];



function getPath( obj, path ) {
  if (!path || !obj) {
    return null;
  }
  const [currentPath, ...rest] = path.split('/');
  const nextPath = rest.join('/');
  const currentObj = obj[currentPath];
  
  // final path, exit here
  if (nextPath.length === 0) {
    return currentObj;
  }
  
  if (Array.isArray( currentObj )) {
    // does an element exit at the next level
    if ( currentObj[nextPath[0]] ) {
      // will continue reading for 1 element
      return getPath( currentObj, nextPath );
    }
    // return all the subpaths, skip the ones that are falsy
    return currentObj.map( item => getPath( item, nextPath ) ).filter( v => v );
  }
  // get the next part of the object
  return getPath( currentObj, nextPath );
}

function getMatchingValues( obj, paths ) {
  return paths.flatMap( path => getPath( obj, path ) ?? false );
}

console.log( getMatchingValues( getPath( data, 'company/result/0' ), pathsToFind ) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been trying to modify your script to get a flat array as output (so: `output = ["one microsoft way", "", mr satya", "mr bradford", 61 "1.57T", ""]`(whenever false, it has to add an element to the array too) but was sot succesful. Where do I make the change? I believe it has to be here `paths.map( path => getPath( obj, path )` but don't understand how to modify.

Comment: @Pr0no just put flatmap behind it, similar to the other code example

Comment: @Pr0no I updated the codesnippet with `paths.flatMap` instead of `paths.map`, you were at the correct place :)

Comment: @Pr0no The more I think about it, the less it makes sense to use `flatMap` because how would you ever manage to map the paths to the output? It would simply be one string after the other, you would never manage to put a meaningful label behind it (and the same with removing the `null` results from subarrays. I guess you might have a usecase for it, but it eludes me. The current example would also work with prepending `company/results/0/` to all of your paths (you would get the same output), but with `company/results/` you would get the names back as an array (flatMap only flattens 1 level)

Comment: I have tried your script in the real world: https://jsfiddle.net/9n3y62sc/19/ but to no succes. I keep getting an error `"<a class='gotoLine' href='#58:25'>58:25</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined"` which I don't understand because it is correctly passing `data` to `getMatchingValues()`. Can you please explain? Trying to learn here, but your javascript is difficult for me to understand ("it's not you, it's me ;)"). The usecase is to push this flatmap into a Google Sheet --- each element goes into a cell.

Comment: @Pr0no don't forget that `fetch` is a promise based approach, you have return the response.json() after the call was succesfull, so `fetch(url).then( response => response.json() )`. So, what it complains about is that the promise doesn't have a `company` property (and you can't ask for a `result` property of undefined)

Answer (score 0):

There are several workarounds for your solution, but I think you might consider the JSONPath solution as a standard way to query your JSON Object.

Check this out [npm JSONPath Guide](https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```js
let data = {
  profile: {
    address: "One Microsoft Way",
    bosses: [
      {
        name: "Mr. Satya  Nadella",
        age: 53,
        totalPay: {
          raw: 13603180,
          fmt: "13.6M",
          longFmt: "13,603,180",
        },
      },
      {
        name: "Mr. Bradford L. Smith",
        age: 61,
        title: "Pres & Chief Legal Officer",
        totalPay: {
          raw: 4265576,
          fmt: "4.27M",
          longFmt: "4,265,576",
        },
      },
    ],
    auditRisk: 1,
  },
  statistics: {
    enterpriseValue: {
      raw: 1570244395008,
      fmt: "1.57T",
    },
    profitMargins: {
      raw: 0.32285,
    },
    financialCurrency: "USD",
  },
};

let paths = [
  "profile/address",
  "profile/sector",
  "profile/bosses/name",
  "profile/bosses/1/age",
  "statistics/enterpriseValue/fmt",
  "profitMargins/fmt",
];

let GenratedResult = paths
  .map((p) => p.split("/"))
  .reduce((allResults, c) => {
    let curRes = c.reduce((innerResults, innerCur) => {
      if (typeof innerResults === "object" && innerResults.length) {
        if (!isNaN(innerCur * 1)) {
          return innerResults[innerCur] || false;
        } else {
          let R = innerResults
            .map((v) => v[innerCur] || false)
            .filter((i) => i);
          return R.length ? R : false;
        }
      }

      return innerResults && innerResults[innerCur]
        ? innerResults[innerCur]
        : false;
    }, data);

    return [...allResults, curRes];
  }, [])
  .flatMap((i) => i);

console.log(GenratedResult);
```